# How to get the body information of an article using the Python SDK in Confluence

Tags: python, confluence

How to get the body information of an article using the Python SDK in Confluence.

hi, I now have A need to synchronize all space A of Site A to space B of site B.

This is the SDK That I use:
https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html#get-page-info

I know how to use the creation of articles, which is a great help to my synchronization work.
But I couldn't get the content of the article with the SDK!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a two-step process

1. get the page id by using `confluence.get_page_id(space, title)`
2. get the page by using `confluence.get_page_by_id(self, page_id, "body.view", status=None, version=None)`

The python api is a thin wrapper around the confluence REST API. So ou'll find most of the explanations here: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/?_ga=2.109597317.1235713429.1594896063-1132282397.1590409375

Comment: I will get the body content and create it through `create_page`, where the HTML tag will trigger 400 errors.

Comment: This is the content of my debug.
`b'{"statusCode":400,"data":{"authorized":false,"valid":true,"allowedInReadOnlyMode":true,"errors":[],"successful":false},"message":"Error parsing xhtml: Unexpected close tag </span>; expected </img>.\\n at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1031]","reason":"Bad Request"}'
`

Comment: https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/issues/542

Comment: When you create the page, you have to use the storage format, not plain html. `"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is <br/> a new page</p>","representation":
"storage"}}` - see https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/#create-a-new-page

Comment: So the SDK doesn't have the ability to translate.
Only through the API?

Comment: Can `get_page_by_id` of the SDK get the body format?

Comment: Yeah it can. But in the his comment he referred to create_page, so I guess that's where he is stuck at the moment.
It also seems like his code is malformed, hence the problem. If the html is xhtml compliant, it should work, IMO